# compare UILabel Score

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have 2 UILables:

myScore.text; and hisScore.text;

When my NSTimer reach 0, I have this code:

```
if (MainInt <= 0) {
        [Mytimer invalidate];

        if (myScore.text < hisScore.text) {
            UIAlertView *win = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You WIN" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [win show];
        }
        else if(myScore.text > hisScore.text) {
            UIAlertView *lose = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hmmmm" message:@"You lose :(" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [lose show];
        }

        else if(myScore.text == hisScore.text) {
            UIAlertView *tie = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not Bad" message:@"No winners. TIE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [tie show];
        }
    }
```

How can I compare, if my score is > than his score? my code doesn't work. Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently comparing two strings.

You will have to compare the integer values for those strings.
To access the integer value of a string in Objective-C, you can use the `intValue` method as such:

```
[myScore.text intValue]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[myScore.text integerValue];
```

Or

```
[myScore.text intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing the text of labels for this? You should have the actual scores in some sort of integer variables in your class. Views should only be used for displaying data, not storing data. If you use ivars of type `int` or some other appropriate data type then you can perform appropriate actions on those values.

Leave the labels to displaying a nicely formatted representation of the data.

But if you insist on using the labels, convert the label text to `int` values first.

```
int scoreA = [myScore.text intValue];
```

Edit: Here's a further explanation of what is wrong with your current code. In Objective-C, the NSString class is, well, a class. It is an object type. When you write:

```
if (myScore.text > hisScore.text)
```

you are actually comparing the two memory addresses of the two string objects. So it makes no sense to compare the two pointers.

You can compare two strings like this:

```
if ([myScore.text compare:hisScore.text] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

but this does an alphabetic comparison, not a numeric comparison.

But the key here is that you rarely want to use standard comparison operators with object pointers. Use the appropriate method to compare the two object values.